# Setting width of EditText on left of icon that is aligned to the end of a parent

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_categories_search"
        style="@style/loginEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/login_edittext_bg"
        android:padding="@dimen/large_spacer" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ib_search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/small_spacer"
        android:src="@drawable/search_icon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have an EditText and ImageButton (an icon in this case) in a horizontal orientation. The icon is aligned to the end of the parent. Is there a way to fill the left side of the icon with the width of the EditText? I don't want to use layout_weight, and I've tried RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, ConstraintLayout but to no avail.

Comment: Add `android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/ib_search"` to `Edittext`.

Comment: I could've sworn that I tried this, or maybe it was layout_alignStart that I used instead. Either way, you are awesome cuz this worked :)

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon a fix moments after posting this question. I mentioned that I didn't want to use layout_weight, that was because I was under the impression that both EditText and ImageButton needed to be provided the attribute.

I left the ImageButton width & height as 'wrap_content', and changed the width of the EditText to 0dp as well as provide a layout_weight attribute of 1. To my shock, it worked.

I'd be more than happy to look at other ways to achieve what I was looking for.